# How to load Jquery when using multiple php files

Tags: php, jquery

I have divided my html-file into a header.php, content.php and footer.php
I would like to load the js files and the document.getready function either in the hader or in the footer file. But I got an error saying: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

In my header.php I load the following scripts in the head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.5/jquery.fancybox.js" async></script>`
```

And in my Footer after the closing `</body>`-Tag I call:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    if( !window.isCMS) {
        // Group images by gallery using data-fancybox-group attributes
        var galleryId = 1;
        $('.editable-gallery').each( function() {
            $(this).find('a').attr('data-fancybox', 'gallery-' + galleryId++);
        });
        $('.editable-gallery').each( function() {
            $(this).find('img').attr('width', '200');
        });
        // Initialize Fancybox

        $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
            // Use the alt attribute for captions per http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful
            //beforeShow: function() {
              //  var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');
                //this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);
                //this.title = alt;
            //}
        });   
    }
});
</script>
```

In my content.php file I include my header.php and footer.php like this:

```
<?php include ("header.php"); ?>
<?php include ("footer.php"); ?>
```

How and where do I have to implement the script files and the document.getready function?

This is my Gallery Code in my content.php: 
`<div id="my-gallery" class="editable-gallery">
<a href="fotos/2018/rl/02022018/3.jpg"><img src="fotos/2018/rl/02022018/3.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a href="fotos/2018/rl/02022018/1.jpg"><img src="fotos/2018/rl/02022018/1.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a href="fotos/2018/rl/02022018/3.jpg"><img src="fotos/2018/rl/02022018/3.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>` 
I have to add the attr "data-fancybox" and "width" to work with fancybox.

Comment: Have you used any jquery code using `$` above the line where you include header.php file?

Comment: Show us the (simplified) html code that will be generated

Comment: thats because you are using `async` attribute in your scripts.

Comment: It was the async attribute. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

**1st:-** The error comes from `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"` it should be `https` instead of `http` >> `src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"`

**2nd:-** you can include js files or js code in `<head>` OR **BEFORE** `</body>`

**3rd:-** you can use `<script></script>` anywhere from `<head>` to `</body>` even before the line you including your jquery **BUT** use `$(document).ready(function(){ //code here })`

**Note:** if you have any plugins you must include the plugins after including jquery

your js code works fine

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //if( !window.isCMS) {
        // Group images by gallery using data-fancybox-group attributes
        var galleryId = 1;
        $('.editable-gallery').each( function() {
            $(this).find('a')
            .attr('data-fancybox', 'gallery-' + galleryId++).find('img').attr('width' , '200');
        });
        // Initialize Fancybox

        $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
            // Use the alt attribute for captions per http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful
            //beforeShow: function() {
              //  var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');
                //this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);
                //this.title = alt;
            //}
        });   
    //}
});
```

```html
<!-- 1. Add latest jQuery and fancyBox files -->

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>


<!-- 2. Create links -->

<div id="my-gallery" class="editable-gallery">
<a href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></a>
<a href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></a>
<a href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></a>
</div>


<!-- 3. Have fun! -->
```

Comment: Problem is still there: This is The Gallery-Code in my content.php

Comment: Above I include my Gallery-Code from the content.php

Comment: @Francisco I updated my answer check the demo it works just fine .. be sure to include your code before `</body>` not after it